# I cant calc a series value by every few bars, its a bug?

Tags: pine-script

my code:

```
var lastatr = 0.0
var wait = 0.0
if wait == 0
  atr := sma(tr(true),length)
  lastatr := atr[0]
  wait := 24
else
  atr := lastatr
if wait > 0
  wait := wait - 1

plot(atr)
```

It dont show my line,nz(atr,100) always returns 100

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

var length  = 5
var atr     = 0.0
var wait    = 0.0

atr  := wait ? atr[0] : sma(tr(true), length)
wait := wait ? wait - 1 : 24

plot(atr)
```

Comment: It works on my end. Screenshot from this script on AAPL daily : https://www.tradingview.com/x/zH0ZCaHx/

Comment: After I change from XBT to AAPL and then change back, it works, its very strange